# How to properly apply heat to loosen screwed-in outer tie rod

Tags: steering, acura, integra, tie-rod

An outer tie rod is bound (screwed into) the inner tie rod as described [in this previous posting.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/38113)

I will replace the tie rods, but plan to keep the jam-nut.  **If I were to apply heat from a propane torch, how would I know when to stop applying heat?**  As I understand it I should just let it cool down (~30 min) and then try to wrench it.  **Seeking any best practices and recommended youTube videos on the subject matter.**

## PROJECT UPDATE

[Tie-rod boot replacement](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38274)

Comment: If the threads are that seized use an oxygen-acetylene torch instead and heat it till it's red. Another option would be a oxygen-map gas setup instead of straight butane. I'd also wrench on the nut when it was still hot and spray it with penetrating oil if it starts to move. I live in an area where they use salt on the roads and some tie-rods are so seized together you have to heat the jam nut until it's red and air hammer the nut to break the rust free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Keep the torch pointed at the exact same spot, don't move it around.
- There is usually dirt or metal shaving nearby that will start to glow orange, that's your cue that it's hot enough. 30 seconds is a good reference, 2 minutes is on the long side.
- Splash some water on it until it stops sizzling. If it didn't sizzle, it wasn't hot enough. The idea of heat is to get the threads to expand, and the idea of splashing water is to shrink the threads quickly, as it may separate them.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of examples I am seeking.  Much appreciated: thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only use this method If you don't plan to keep using the stuff you're heating. If you splash water all over, the temperature drops much and fast, hardening the metal. Sounds better but it also makes it brittle. not what you want. If you can throw away your tie rods fter you can perfectly do this.

Comment: When something is this seized, it ain't going back on anything I drive. Not only the heat-damage from this removal technique, but the wrenching will most likely mess-up the head.