# Tie-rod boot replacement

Tags: acura, installation, integra, tie-rod

Goal: install tie-rod 'bellows' boot.

Having unusual difficulty seating the inner (larger side) boot on the steering assembly. Unable to see and must do it by feel because this Acura only has access form the side \ wheel well with limited space

***Seeking tips for seating the inner side of the boot.***  Using OEM bellows: expecting maximum probability of a proper fit

If you have had success using a particular technique installing a tie rod 
boot: please state this in your response.  Double bonus if experience includes an Integra \ Civic.  Thank you

## UPDATE: SUCCESSFUL INSTALL

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a Service Manager for and Acura dealership. Also an ASE master tech. Put the boot in hot water for a few minutes. This will soften the boot, making it more pliable, allowing you to push/slide it in place. They are very tight so they will seal well and have a ridge to help keep them in place. You can put a little grease on he inner lip of the boot, but sometimes that makes it worse. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have an approximate temperature and time to soak the boot in hot water?  Your comment and insight is seriously appreciated!

Comment: Just long enough to soften it. It can take fairly high heat but I would say less than boiling.

Comment: Excellent comment and insight.  A little bit of vaseline lip-balm made all the difference.  Thank you for your help: see the fruit of your comment in the original post :)